# Sharepoint : Refused to display URL in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am trying to open a my site page url as a modal dialog using SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog from a different site collection, but got this error

Refused to display ‘URL’ in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Tried changing the HTML security for my site collection by adding the domain to the allowed list . But didn’t help .  Am I missing something?

Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Html Field Security

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps.aspx

Allowing your SharePoint-hosted pages to be IFRAMED
SharePoint page developers can opt-out of clickjacking protection by adding the AllowFraming control to their .aspx pages:

This control instructs SharePoint not to send the X-Frame-Options header when this page is requested. Without the X-Frame-Options header, the page is able to be IFRAMED.